# Creating a mathematical "or" in array function?

Tags: excel, matrix

I have the following information given:

```
Airplane Typ Destination
Typ A         LAX
Typ B         LAX
Typ A         NEW
Typ A         NEW
Typ B         NEW
Typ C         ROS
Typ D         MUI
```

Now I want to have the total number of flights which go to NEW with airplane typ A. So I use the formula:

> =SUM((A1:A5)='Typ A')*(B1:B5='NEW))

and I close this with strg shift enter so it gives a matrix formula. This works and I get the result 2. Now what do I have to enter, if I want the number of flights which use the Airplane Typ A or go to NEW? The result should be 4 of course.

Comment: Try the [COUNTIF function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/countif-function-4764f197-0127-49fa-9f5a-b188177b6db) or [COUNTIFS function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/COUNTIFS-function-53C4DC8E-0E5B-4E32-93DF-9CA5E7DA89ED). BTW, the term you should be using is *array formula*, not *matrix formula*.

Comment: Of course I can? When I enter this formula and close it with strg shift and enter it works fine?

Comment: Yes ok thanks, I also now that for the and conditions I could use countifs function. So =countifs(A1:A5;"=Typ A"; B1:B5;"=NEW"). But what if the logical condition is a "or"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your existing formula would be better written as a standard formula instead of an array formula.

```
=COUNTIFS(A2:A6, "Typ A", B2:B6, "NEW")
```

The [COUNTIFS function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/COUNTIFS-function-53C4DC8E-0E5B-4E32-93DF-9CA5E7DA89ED) does not really process an `OR` condition but you can stack them together or use [SUMPRODUCT function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMPRODUCT-function-57a7bfa7-f74d-4ead-8c93-57f759c8f616) for that. The COUNTIFS is much more efficient than SUMPRODUCT.

```
=COUNTIF(A2:A6, "Typ A")+COUNTIF(B2:B6, "new")-COUNTIFS(A2:A6, "Typ A", B2:B6, "NEW")
```

Equivalent SUMPRODUCT would be,

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(((A2:A6="Typ A")+(B2:B6="new"))>0))
```

Comment: Thanks! But what does the "--" in the formula at the beginning stand for?

Comment: Maybe you could google or bing [excel double unary](https://www.bing.com/search?q=excel+double+unary) or [excel double minus](https://www.bing.com/search?q=excel+double+minus) ...?

Comment: Can the "--" be avoided somehow?

Comment: No. You cannot add TRUE+TRUE. But by using a mathematical operation on the booleans, you convert them to 1+1. Your original formula performs this task by multiplying the two booleans against each other. Try `=SUM(((A1:A5)="Typ A"))`. It won't work. But try `=SUM(--((A1:A5)="Typ A"))` and it will.